# SOAP XML with AS3

Tags: xml, actionscript-3, parsing, soap

I have been banging my head against a wall for the last couple of hours, and need a little advice on how to get around a ( what I think is weird) problem.

I am connecting to a .NET webservice, and passing it a couple of parameters and getting back some XML wrapped up in SOAP.

I found it pretty fussy to get through all of the SOAP headers to get to the data i wanted to interact with. As it appeared you couldn't iterate through it like normal XML.

var soapEnvelope:XML = new XML(serviceResponse.children()[0][0][0].toXMLString());

So anyway when I trace out my XML from the webservice I get this:

```
<data xmlns="http://services.xxx.com" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <CurrencyPrice>
    <CurrencyID>8</CurrencyID>
    <CurrencyFlagImagePath/>
    <MidRate>x.xxxx</MidRate>
    <CurrencyCode>AUD</CurrencyCode>
    <CurrencyName>Australian Dollar (AUD)</CurrencyName>
    <BaseCurrency>GBP</BaseCurrency>
    <CurrencyChartURL/>
  </CurrencyPrice>
</data>
```

Now If I would usually use trace(xml.CurrencyPrice[0]); To have a look at the first CurrencyPrice node. But I get an undefined. If I copy out the original trace and create the XML manually and remove all the data xlmns attributes

```
var xml:XML = <data>
  <CurrencyPrice>
    <CurrencyID>8</CurrencyID>
    <CurrencyFlagImagePath/>
    <MidRate>x.xxxx</MidRate>
    <CurrencyCode>AUD</CurrencyCode>
    <CurrencyName>Australian Dollar (AUD)</CurrencyName>
    <BaseCurrency>GBP</BaseCurrency>
    <CurrencyChartURL/>
  </CurrencyPrice>
</data> ;
```

then trace(xml.CurrencyPrice[0]);

Boom get some XML I can work with.

So my question is how do I delete the attributes from the header I have tried using a delete method targeting .@xlmns. Doesn't do anything, or getting around it in ANY another way.

I would appreciate any advice on this, having googled the crap out of it I am not getting anywhere.

Cheers

Jono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried Alducente's [as3 Web Service](http://alducente.wordpress.com/2007/10/27/web-service-in-as3-release-10/) library ?

Comment: I am using Alducente's library, but did not find any event for IOError. Do you know?

Comment: Please bare in mind I haven't used this library in 8 years, so my suggestion might not be 100% accurate. If you look at the `WSDL` class in the source code at it's `getWSDL` method you'll notice there's a single event listener added: `urlLoader.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, wsdlLoaded);`. I suggest you modify `getWSDL`'s signature to include callbacks for any missing events you need (e.g. IOError/SecurityError/etc.), trigger the callbacks so they propagate to `WebService` and from there dispatch events. This will allow you to add IOError/SecurityError handlers to your `WebService` instance.

Answer (score 2):

Can't you say something like this?

```
var raw:String = xml.toXMLString();
//filter the String of namespaces
//and then recreate the xml
var clean:XML = new XML(raw);
```

And then obviously do your normal XML practices....

```
trace(clean.CurrencyPrice[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

When using namespaces you'll need to make use of the namespace declaration in AS3.

```
public namespace soap = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/";
```

Then you would be able to access the subproperties with:

```
trace(xml.soap::CurrencyPrice.soap::CurrencyID);
```

However, as you're using multiple namespaces it's going to look MUCH more messy. I've found this reference from someone else who appears to have had the same problem, but with only two namespaces. I don't know how it'll look with four!

http://headwindslab.net/2009/01/29/parsing-multiple-namespaces-in-as3/

Good luck! :)